# How to check with loops how many times user punched a password?

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

On my homework assignment I have to set up a test that ask the user for the password ( three times). If the user punches wrong password three times, then I must display a message " Wrong password". Also I have to take into account three variants of the username and password

I am thinking that I set up a predefined passwords like "test", "password" and so on. The same I will do with the usernames. So basically I just know how to count how many times the user punches the username and password...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

  <script>

  var password = "";

  while(password = "" || password != "password"||username !="Bella"||username="") {
username=prompt ("What´s your username?);    
passord = prompt("What´s the password?");
  }

  alert("That was correct!");

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What´s the username?
What´s the password?

wrong - typed 3 times
That was correct

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

  <script>
    var incorrectCount = 0;
    var correctPassword = "randompassword"
    function checkPassword(){
        var enteredPassword  = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
        if(enteredPassword != correctPassword)
            incorrectCount++
        else{
            incorrectCount = 0
            document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "Correct Password !!"
        }

        if(incorrectCount == 3){
            document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "Incorrect password entered 3 or more times"
            document.getElementById("userMessage").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
  </script>

  <input type="text" id="txtpassword" name ="txtpassword">
  <input type="button" id="loginbutton" value="Login" onclick="checkPassword()"><br>
  <label id="userMessage" style="visibility:hidden;"></label>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. You do not need a loop for this.
2. You can just have a global variable and increment it every time user enters wrong password.
3. Once the counter reaches 3, you can show the message.
4. Please refer the code above.

**Also, try searching for stuff like - how can I validate a input, how can I display/show a message - this will help you in learning**