# HTML How to make login form take me to a website

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML

(check edits)

It might be messy, I'm really really new to making a website (I use neocities.org )
I used an HTML Source, but made it a bit for myself. Haven't yet figured out how to remove the white around the boxes, but will figure out later.

But wanted to know how I make this form, have a correct 'answer' that will take me to a new site

site url: https://labavakara.neocities.org/main.html

**EDITS:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>


<style>
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 55%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
body {
 background-image: url("https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgetwallpapers.com%2Fwallpaper%2Ffull%2F4%2Fc%2Fc%2F36974.jpg&f=1&nofb=1");
 background-color: #cccccc;
}
function {
  color: red;
}

</style>

<body>


  <script>
    var incorrectCount = 0;
    var correctPassword = "randompassword"
    function checkPassword(){
        var enteredPassword  = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
        if(enteredPassword != correctPassword)
            incorrectCount++
        else{
            incorrectCount = 0
            document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "Correct Password !!"
            window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
        }

        if(incorrectCount == 3){
            document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "Incorrect password entered 3 or more times"
            document.getElementById("userMessage").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
  </script>



  <div>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
     <title>Login</title>




<form>
        <p><input style="background-color:red;color:black;border:1px solid #ff0000" type="text" id="randompassword" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
        <p><input style="background-color:red;color:black;border:1px solid #ff0000" type="password" id="something" name="password" value="" placeholder="********"></p>
           <a class="submit"><input type="submit" id="loginbutton" onclick="checkPassword()" name="commit" value="Login"><br>
             <label id="userMessage" style="visibility:hidden;"></label>


</a>

  </form>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The index.html in    <form method="post" action="index.html"> is the target address (url) if clicked on the type="submit" input. Name and password are Always send with the method="post" to prevent others to see the password. So you can't send this to a website that is not of yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://google.com">
        <p><input style="background-color:red;color:black" type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
        <p><input style="background-color:red;color:black" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="********"></p>
        <a class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
</form>
```

1. If you just want to redirect to any publicly hosted website like google,stack overflow etc **remove POST method** as it means that you are POSTING (pushing/sending some data to that website for processing)
2. Use **http:// or https://** - if you do not use these for public websites, the code will try to search for that particular page/website in your html page directory.

**EDIT - 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 55%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
body {
 background-image: url("https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgetwallpapers.com%2Fwallpaper%2Ffull%2F4%2Fc%2Fc%2F36974.jpg&f=1&nofb=1");
 background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>

<body>

  <script>
    var incorrectCount = 0;
    var correctPassword = "randompassword"
    var correctLoginId  = "randomlogin"
    function checkPassword(){
        var enteredLogin  = document.getElementById("txtUserId").value;
        var enteredPassword  = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
        if(enteredPassword == correctPassword && enteredLogin == correctLoginId){
            incorrectCount = 0
            document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "Correct Password !!"
            window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
        }
        else{
            incorrectCount++
        }

        if(incorrectCount == 3){
            document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "Incorrect password entered 3 or more times"
            document.getElementById("userMessage").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
  </script>



  <div>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
     <title>Login</title>




        <p><input style="background-color:red;color:black;border:1px solid #ff0000" type="text" id="txtUserId" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
        <p><input style="background-color:red;color:black;border:1px solid #ff0000" type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password" value="" placeholder="********"></p>
        <input type="submit" id="loginbutton" onclick="checkPassword()" name="commit" value="Login"><br>
        <label id="userMessage" style="visibility:hidden;color:red;"></label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I replaced that code with yours and it just ended up with a few errors. Can't figure out what end tags I'm missing

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. How do I make it so there's a correct  and the only login for it to direct me to a new site?

Comment: I edited my answer with your code along with the changes.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to put validation ? Like only when you enter correct password it redirects you to the site ?

Comment: I want there to be a correct username and password.
For example, username: admin. password: admin and it redirects you to a site.

Comment: For something like this, you would need JavaScript.

I answered a similar post here for password validation :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019095/how-to-check-with-loops-how-many-times-user-punched-a-password/58019992#58019992

Along with this use : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp
To validate and then redirect.

Comment: I'll try that rn @ViralSinha

Comment: Is there a way to add another color of the scripts text? Since my background is set to black, I can't see anything written.
Also, is the id of the inputs, the correct password or is it randompassword?
I haven't changed the script expect for adding window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com"; after IncorrectCount = 0

Comment: var correctPassword = "randompassword"

So hard-coded or predefined password is "randompassword", whatever you enter it will try to match with this and accordingly it will show error/proceed to other page. You can change it to whatever password you want, it is just a variable [not the correct way to do this, as your JavaScript source is visible always, but because it is for learning purpose, you can do like this for now]

Comment: Regarding script text color, you can have custom css, or inline css for your elements.

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: (Also, this is gonna redirect to a site of mine)
So I tried typing whatever after doing css, made it so
function {
color:red;
}
and tested the site, did multiple wrong passwords, did the good password - nothing  happens at all

Comment: check the console in chrome developer tools, there could be a error in some of your changes.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () style.css

Imma try Bron's comment also

Comment: I got rid of the error, but the problem stays that nothing happens. Do I have to do a duplicate script for the 2nd input?

Comment: Can you edit your questions and post the new version of the code ?

Comment: done. I also tried only making one input, but that doesn't show any changes

Comment: Give me 5 minutes, I'll check and get back.

Comment: You have used id "txtpassword" in your javascript, but in your input the id is different, you have used "randompassword" there.

So how it works is that, onclick of the button the javascript function is called and it gets the elementbyId("Id of the element whose value you want to check ") and then compares.

So it should be something like this : 
var enteredPassword  = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;

var login = document.getElementById("id of the login input").value;

Comment: Follow these steps :
1. Give your inputs proper id's {Something like passwordInput and loginInput}
2. in your script, take value of elements by id in two variables (one for input, one for password) 
3. Write comparison condition for both ( like: password = "" && login = "") and then redirect.

Comment: Elements are the ones which say document.getElementById("txtpassword").value; right?
And the value is gonna be txtpassword

Comment: No.

document.getElementById("txtpassword").value -> this whole thing gives you whatever you enter in "txtpassword" textbox.

Comment: something like this ?
 var input = document.getElementById("loginInput");   
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordInput");

Comment: Yes, and I was able to find out the issue, since you are not using any post/get with your form, you can remove form element.

Posting the changed code in my answer as edit.

Comment: All good now. I figured it all out.
Found this in a thread 
function check(form)
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.loginInput.value == "admin" && form.passwordInput.value == "labadiena")
  {
    window.open('google.com')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  }
 else
 {
   alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
  }
}

Comment: Check the updated answer.

1. Also this method is not recommended for any login-based website, this is just for your learning purpose.
2. It is always good to have a server which validates the user credentials at the server side.

Once you are done with this, you can look at : https://makitweb.com/create-simple-login-page-with-php-and-mysql/ or if you prefer any other language then search and you will get plenty of articles for the same.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me xd

Comment: Happy to help !

Comment: Yeah I figured I should add some txt file or something, I'll see what I can do at the server files. So people won't see login by inspect element. PHP is restricted for me

Comment: I could maybe make it so the script goes to the file, checks if the info matches and then redirects

Comment: Is there a way for a script to send an ID to a .js file? or .json, .geojson

Comment: and then make the script send back something?

Comment: If it will be only you logging in, then you can try this approach and search on it, but if this will be available for multiple users then all users need to have the same .json or raw file for doing that validation. It does not seem like a good approach. 

Have a look at this anyway, it might help you :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-program-to-read-text-file/

Comment: How do I import fs.js into html?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199788/discussion-on-answer-by-viral-sinha-html-how-to-make-login-form-take-me-to-a-web).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to process form data in html/css of the receiving page. If you leave out method="post" it will be method="get", then the form data is send after the question (?) mark in the url. In that case you can use Javascript in the receiving page to process the form data.

If using method="post" then you can use php to process the form data.
Below you'll find the html that sends the input values to process.php

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
  <p><input type="text" name="login" value=""></p>
  <p><input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
  <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
</form>
```

In file process.php you read the form data and can do whatever you like.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = (!isset($_POST['login']))    ? "" : trim($_POST['login']);
  $pass = (!isset($_POST['password'])) ? "" : trim($_POST['password']);
  // here you can do something with $name and $pass
}
?>
```

Comment: It's the main page. I wanna make it so I put in a correct username and password and it takes me to another site of my own.

So do I get the process.php in my server and make the 'login' and 'password' as the correct ones or what?

Comment: I can't even make a .php file in neocities

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead, might just fit your description

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Godwyne/E-Bank/master/Project/index.php

Comment: Can I remove the sign up? I want there to be only one login and also I've already done this all. But the only thing that is left  is to hide the login info